# crystal report substring

Tags: crystal-reports

SUBSTRING(SLAC_CNTRL_ACNO, 3, 4)

how can i use this query in crystal report

Answer (score 1):

Instead of substring, Crystal Reports uses `mid` function:

```
mid(SLAC_CNTRL_ACNO, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the entire SQL query needs to be in a Command OR you can use a SQL Expression field if the sub-query returns a scalar value.

See my posting, [Crystal Reports: Using SQL Expression Fields](http://www.cogniza.com/blog/?p=26).

Comment: but how can i import to crystal report formula editor
it contains many function except substring